# Why do people use if(null == var) style tests?

Tags: java, if-statement, language-agnostic, coding-style

Some folks, typically those that come from a C background, code their tests for `null` like this:

```
if (null == someVar)
```

in the belief that the "normal" style

```
if (someVar == null)
```

might accidentally be coded as

```
if (someVar = null)
```

which would inadvertently *assign* a `null` instead of *test* for `null`.

However, if a mis-coding such as `if (someVar = null)` occurred:

1. In order to compile, the only type `someVar` can be is `Boolean`
2. If it did compile and was executed, it would throw a `NullPointerException`

Why don't these people realise that the "defensive" (ie screw ball) style doesn't help at all, because a mis-coding either wouldn't compile or wouldn't run!?

BTW, as a matter of performance, coding `if (null == someVar)` is actually slightly slower to execute - one instruction slower to be precise. The reason is the `null` must be pushed onto the stack for comparison, whereas the "normal" style uses the special "is null" instruction.

I know... Not really a question. More a rant. But I wanted to put it out there. Upvote if you also believe they are "less than insightful".

However, if you do know the answer, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: Preference? Or they assume they're Yoda. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html

Comment: _normal_ style for expressions involving `null`, yoda conditions for the rest? That would be inconsistent.

Comment: You have really answered your own question - it is because the language that they have come from *did* allow assignments that wouldn't compile in the language they are now using - so they need to re-learn based on the language they are using.

Comment: The answer's in the question.  It's due to their background.  A bit like asking why those with an Eastern States background are always complaining

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because they bring back this habit from C, where

```
if (someInteger = 0)
```

is valid code, since C doesn't have booleans, but only integers (0 being false, and every other integer being true).

```
if (somePointer = NULL)
```

is also valid, since in C, NULL is 0.

So, in C, this construct makes sense.

Note that in Java, this bug can also occur when doing

```
if (b = true)
```

instead of

```
if (b == true)
```

Of course, a good Java developer will never write the above, but will use

```
if (b)
```

Comment: +1 Actually this is about as good an answer as could be expected for this "question".

Comment: You might be interested to know that `if (null == var)` is slower to execute than `if (var == null)` - see question edit

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem writing `if (null == someVar)` so why not?  It's not a bad idea for people who have adopted this convention from their C/C++ background to keep the same convention for Java; especially if they are still writing in C/C++; otherwise they end up having to use two different conventions for two languages instead of having a single common one.

Simple question of habit without any real bad side effect.

Answer (score 0):

It's sometimes useful to scope variables in this way:

```
if(std::shared_ptr<X> p = q.lock())
{
    // q is valid, I can now use p.

    p->DoSomething();
}
```

q.lock() != 0 evaluates to TRUE.  q.lock() == 0 evaluates to FALSE.  The coding style given above would make the intention explicit.  However these days compilers are quite clever at spotting unintended assignments, so it isn't really necessary.  In the past this wasn't the case.

Comment: FYI, this is a *java* question

Comment: Reference made to the C language (C++ too).  This is where I've seen it most often and explains its origin.